# prettyPhoto gallery opens too low on the screen and moves down as you scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, prettyphoto

I am helping with a website that uses prettyPhoto, and they are experiencing an odd issue where when you click to open the gallery, it appears low on the page (often below the current window view), and when you scroll down it keeps moving down, staying outside of the view.

With developer tools I can change the style for the top position on the "pp_pic_holder pp_default" div, and move it to the top (like top: 0px) -- so it appears to be showing up correctly, and I think it's just not calculating the top position correctly.

What is wrong/different with this website and how can I change it so prettyPhoto appears in the expected location when it opens?

Here's the website:

http://concernedpeopleforanimals.org/adoptionsDogs.html

If you click on one of the pets, then click one of their pictures, the Gallery will open.

I do not own/manage this website, I'm just trying to get the pet search to work (and it does work find on dozens of other websites).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that the websites that were experiencing this issue were not specifying a doctype.  As soon as they added a doctype the issue went away.

Comment: It was the issue in my case indeed. Thanks!